# How to use required_if on file array fields with an array for first argument?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I have an with an array of image_file (`image_file[1]`, `image_file[2]`). They are input of type file.
This images are required only if another array of fields (proposition_type) is defined on 2.

For example :

- if `proposition_type[1] == 2`,  `image_file[1]` has to be filled ;
- if
  `proposition_type[2] == 1`,  `image_file[2]` has not to be filled.

I have tried to use the following rules :

```
$rules = [
    (...)
    'image_file.*' => 'required_if:proposition_type.*,2|image',
];
```

But any error on image_file fields is raised.

Moreover, I have used the `required` validator on my `image_file.*` and, here again, no error is raised.

Maybe someone has a solution for this? Or maybe am I doing something wrong? :)

Thanks!

Comment: I think you will need to write a function to handle this. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: Yes ! Thanks Mike :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did finally was to generate (complete, to be precise) my rules array on the fly, by making a `while`, and adding an array entry for each images.

```
$i = 1;
$total_images = count($image_array);
while ($i <= $image_array)
{
    $this->rules['image_file.'.$i] = 'nullable|required_if:proposition_type.'.$i.',2|image';
    $i++;
}
```

This, of course, need your form to have inputs with `image_file1`, `image_file2`, ... names.

Hope it will help others!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to construct a more complex condition for the required_if rule, you may use the Rule::requiredIf method. This methods accepts a boolean or a Closure. When passed a Closure, the Closure should return true or false to indicate if the field under validation is required. Something like this may work for you:

```
 Validator::make($request->all(), [
 'image_file[1]' => Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($request) {
     if($request->proposition_type[1] == 2)
        return true;
     else
        return false;
 }),
 'image_file[2]' => Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($request) {
     if($request->proposition_type[2] == 1)
        return false;
     else
        return true;
 }),
]);
```

Comment: The thing is that I don't know how many image_file are sent, so I have to generate the table dynamically, etc...

Thanks for the answer.