# Laravel6 multi dimensional array validation

Tags: laravel-6, php-8

I am creating a recipe posting application with Laravel6.

I have implemented a mechanism to dynamically add an image submission form in JavaScript.

I set the validation in FormRequest, but the mandatory input validation for dynamically added form fields does not work.

**blade**

```
<input type="file" name="upload_image[cooking_image][]" class="howto-image" style="display:none" accept="image/*">
```

**FormRequest**

```
 public function rules(Request $request)
    {       
        return [
            'upload_image.cooking_image.*' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg',
        ];
    }
```

But the following works.

**FormRequest**

```
 public function rules(Request $request)
    {       
        return [
            'upload_image.cooking_image.0' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg',
            'upload_image.cooking_image.1' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg',
            'upload_image.cooking_image.2' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg',
            'upload_image.cooking_image.3' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg',
            'upload_image.cooking_image.4' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg',
        ];
    }
```

I want to make mandatory input validation work for all dynamically added form input fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it sometimes not really possible to make it easily dynamic. Personally, in those case, I update my rules array on the fly.

I think this should help you : [How to use required_if on file array fields with an array for first argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55595649/how-to-use-required-if-on-file-array-fields-with-an-array-for-first-argument)

Good luck!